# Where is Bob tweeting from?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Your friend Bob burnt out at his job, and went abroad for a long vacation<sup>1</sup>. He tweeted this today. Where is he ?

[image]

<sup>1 <sub>Note that Bob is not subject to lockdown since he is a hat.</sub></sup>

---

Hint

> The whole "Bob" part is just for fun. The actual puzzle consists in the three hashtags, and the question "Where is he?"

Comment: rot13 [ Oneonqbf be Onunznf ] ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User @Kvothe made a brilliant breakthrough in their answer and came up with a really great suggestion for the answer. However, I believe the correct answer is that Bob is actually in:

> **BELGIUM**

As @Kvothe noted:

> The three 'hashtags', each comprising 6 words following a '#' symbol, actually represent "[hex triplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors)" - the 6-digit [hexadecimal colour codes](https://www.color-hex.com/) used in web and software design. In general, the first letter of each word (which tends to range between A-F or 'O', for zero - all valid hexadecimal numbers) is used as one of the hex triplet digits.
>
>  However, as @Kvothe surmised, the word '*To*' does not have a valid hexadecimal digit for an initial, and instead it should be interpreted as a *homophone* for the number '2'. What they then didn't realise is that ***'To' is not the only word here with a number homophone!*** We also need to apply this rule for the words '*Fore*' and '*For*' (both '4') and also (more loosely) '*Free*' ('3'). This means that the original hashtags, which were:
>
>  *#OnlyObeyedObtuseOrders...OverdueOutburst!*
>  *#First,DabbedDiscretly;Afterwards,ToFore!*
>  *#EnjoyingFeelingFree,FreeForOnce!*
>
>  should translate into the hex triplets:
>
>  **#000000**
>  **#FDDA24**
>  **#EF3340**

What are these?

> These colours translate as **Black**, **Banana Yellow** and **Deep Carmine Pink**.

So where is Bob?

> He's in the country whose tricolour flag consists of these specific colours. In other words, he is in [**Belgium**](https://www.schemecolor.com/belgium-flag-colors.php)!
>
>  [image: Flag of Belgium]
>  <sup>*Image source: Wikipedia*</sup>

Comment: This is exactly what I had in mind. Kudos to you and Kvothe for the joined effort :)

Answer (score 14):

> Jamaica  
>   
> #OOOOOO  
> #FDDA2F (To=Two)  
> #EFFFFO  
>  Hex colors: #000000=**black**, #FDDA2F=**yellow**, #EFFFF0=**green**  
>   
>  [image]  
>   
>  And of course, **Bob** Marley

Comment: So close ! rot13(Gur ynfg pbybe vf vapbeerpg. Gur guerr pbybef pbeerfcbaq gb gur erny bssvpvny urknqrpvzny pbybef bs n angvba'f synt (abg Wnznvpn). Gur Obo cneg vf pbzcyrgryl havagragvbany ohg vg'f fb terng V jnag gb xrrc Wnznvpn nf gur nafjre ;))